# Can I update ModelState.IsValid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my controller I have the following code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(AdEntry adentry)
    {

            adentry.adDate = DateTime.Now;
            adentry.adExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(32);
            adentry.adConfirmationID = rKeyGen(8);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Items.Add(adentry);
                db.SaveChanges();
                TempData["Summary"] = adentry;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

        return View(adentry);
    }
```

In my Model I have this property:

```
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirmation Id is Required.")]
    [StringLength(8, ErrorMessage = "{0} is too long.")]
    public virtual String adConfirmationID { get; set; }
```

When I try to create a new Item ModelState.IsValid = false.  The error I get is that Confiramtion Id is Required.  I am setting the adConfirmationID = to a value right above the check.  How can I get this check to pass?

Comment: Why do you have the Required attribute if you are going to give it a value in the controller?

Comment: @cheesemacfly because I wanted to make sure that it was there always (especially in this instance).  Is that not the right approach?

Comment: But at the time of binding your model is not valid. Can `rKeyGen` return a `null` value?

Comment: No it isn't supposed to.  I just want to make sure that it didn't error somehow and pass a null value

Comment: I have a similar problem. My entity needs simillar adictions after POST information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
ModelState.Remove("adConfirmationID")
```

Place this code before checking `ModelState.IsValid`

This will fix your issue.

Comment: I imagine that this will get me past my issue.  I'm more curious as to why when I'm setting it the IsValid check fails.  And how I can get it to pass (without having to remove the field from being checked)?

Comment: @webdad3, rather than assigning value at controller, create a hidden field for this field in your view and assign value at that point. This will valid your model state.

Answer (score 0):

There are Two ways to handle this issue one is you remove the updated/invalid field from ModelState by this

```
ModelState.Remove("foo");
```

or you have to pass the value to controller from View by using the hidden field

```
 <input type="hidden" asp-for="foo"/>
```